# how to get QR code type

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am  working with Zxing library to decode QR code for android. I can get QR Code. Now, I want to catch what types of QR code it returns say (URL,Phone Nubmer,Plain Text etc). I tried to explore [ResultParser](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/client/result/ResultParser.java?r=2283) class but i can't use it.

**Updated**: I remove my wrong procedure using ResultParser class.

Here is my onActivityResult Code.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        // check the contents strings here 
          //  Need to get actual return type of result 
            if (contents.contains("https:") || contents.contains("http:")) {
                aBarcode.setBarcode_Type(WEB_URL);
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(contents));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            } else {
                aBarcode.setBarcode_Type(PLAIN_TEXT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contents,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            barcodeList.add(aBarcode);
            // show previous barcodes detail
            showBarcodeReaderHistory();
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e("Barcode Result", "Result canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated** :I open ScanActivity like:

```
// start scan after button click
        btnScanQRCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(
                 "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                 intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
```

Hope, i clear it to all. Waiting for your great knock. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modifie the `CaptureActivity` of the library to get the QR Code type into your Activity.

In `CaptureActivity` there is a method name `handleDecodeExternally` which returns the data to your Activity add this line

```
intent.putExtra("QR_TYPE", getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()));
```

before the Activity finishes.

And then get this value to your Activity's `onActivityResult`

```
String type = intent.getStringExtra("QR_TYPE");
```

Finally you have the type of QR Code.

Thank you

### **Edit**

In your zixing library project under `com.google.zxing.client.android` package there is an Activity named `CaptureActivity`. And on that Activity there is `method` named `handleDecodeExternally` which Briefly show the contents of the barcode, then handle the result outside Barcode Scanner. In that method there is an intent by which you have send the data what you found on QR to your activity.

add that line before you leave this activity, After adding it will be like this --

```
      // ------------- Mine Added -------------------
      intent.putExtra("QR_TYPE", getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()));
      // --------------------------------------------

      sendReplyMessage(R.id.return_scan_result, intent);
```

i think you will find this `sendReplyMessage(R.id.return_scan_result, intent);` in 650 +/- line in `CaptureActivity`. Thank you

Comment: where i add intent.putExtra("QR_TYPE", getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()));  ?

Comment: You have to change the zixing library's source code in order to get the QR Code type as by default they didn't return the type. Only returns SCAN_RESULT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT, SCAN_RESULT_BYTES and SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be getting the result from the returned `Intent`'s extras yourself.
Instead, do it like so:

```
IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
```

You can then get all the data you need through the `IntentResult`. Specifically to get the type, you can call `scanResult.getFormatName()`

Comment: The IntentResult class is in the package com.google.zxing.integration.android

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, I would recommend checking out [zxing's Scanning Via Intent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) guide.

Comment: Import the integration folder as well. If you are launching intents to let Zxing handle the scanning anyway, the `IntentIntegrator` is the way to go.

Comment: thanks sir,for your great knock. I got an error, after i successfully importing the above class. LIke:

06-05 00:45:36.215: E/AndroidRuntime(22453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.agv.qrcodereaderscanner/com.agv.qrcodereaderscanner.QRActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Unfortunately the NullPointerException got cut off. Track it down in your code. Figure out what variable is null and why. If it is the IntentResult, did you launch the Intent through the IntentIntegrator?

Comment: IntentResult object is null; i don't launch the Intent through IntentIntegrator.

Comment: Follow the entire [Scanning via Intent guide](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent), and I think you will find that everything works as expected.